# Regex finding duplicate numeric values in a text file

Tags: regex

I have a text file with the values that look like this -

```
#3#6796#
#8226#16#
#8227#16#
#8256#8033#
#8254#8256#8033#
#8270#8256#8033#
#8272#8256#8033#
#8242#8081#
#8241#8242#8081#
#8243#8242#8081#
#8254#8242#8081#
#8265#8242#8081#
```

Number can be of any length but typically they are from 1 to 5 digits.
I need to find duplicate(s) numbers in one particular string (e.g. not the whole file)

So, for example I need to find strings like -

```
#8241#8241#8081#
#8243#8242#8243#
#8254#8242#8254#
#8081#8242#8081#
```

(you can see repeating number in each string above - these are the ones of interest)...
I cannot figure out regex for this, so far I was only able to find dup's in whole file but that's not what I need...

Comment: This question without the language or tool used makes no sense. Please hover the "regex" tag below your question.

Comment: by means of what ... javascript, php or linux `grep`?

Comment: no language as such, pure regex, just need to find duplicate number in a text file. so, any text file process editor...like notepad++ for instance

Comment: Strange that this Q gets all those down votes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b
```

It'll find a number (thank's to the word boundaries - `\b` - only whole numbers) and then match anything `.*` until the number is found again (`\1` back reference). If the repeating one isn't found it doesn't match.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sN5cH4/1).

Regards

Comment: Better use `\b(\d++)\b.*\b\1\b`, otherwise `3#23` will match.

Comment: @SebastianProske I won't argue that without testing, but my initial thought was that since the boundary is inside the capture it'll be used in the back reference match as well.

Comment: @SebastianProske And I tested... And you're right. I must say I'm surprised though... Changing the answer.

Comment: Backreferences will not take zero-length-assertions into consideration that were made for the inital match, they just try to match the content of the group they are referencing at, so these assertions have to be made for the backreference again, if they are necessary. This is consistent for all regex-engines I know.