# Regex to remove duplicate numbers from a string

Tags: regex, knime

I have produced a data set with codes separated by pipe symbols. I realized there are many duplicates in each row.
Here are three example rows (the regex is applied to each row individually in KNIME)

```
0612|0613|061|0612|0612
0211|0612|021|0212|0211|0211
0111|0111
0511|0512|0511|0511|0521|0512|0511
```

I am trying to build a regex that removes the duplicate code numbers from each row.
I tested `\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b` from a different [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37156933/regex-finding-duplicate-numeric-values-in-a-text-file) here but the expression does not keep the other codes. The desired outputs for the example rows above would be

```
0612|0613|061
0211|0612|021|0212
0111
0511|0512|0521
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: *4 example rows actually

Comment: You can't do this with a regexp. It won't do overlapping replacements.

Comment: Why does the last sample output have duplicate `0512`? Do you only care about duplicates of the first number?

Comment: Why is `0111|0111` becoming `0111` but `|0612|0612` is getting removed completely?

Comment: I don't know about knime, but with most languages you could easily do that without a regex. In Ruby, for example, `a = "0211|0612|021|0212|0211|0211".split('|') #=> ["0211", "0612", "021", "0212", "0211", "0211"]`, then `b = a.uniq #=> ["0211", "0612", "021", "0212"]`, then `b.join('|') #=> "0211|0612|021|0212"`. In fact, these operations would be combined: `"0211|0612|021|0212|0211|0211".split('|').uniq.join('|')`. The reader should be able to see how these operations could be translated to other languages.

Comment: @Cary you are right, in KNIME your proposed approach without regex will also work, although it would require more “steps” (or so-called nodes) to get the result (as KNIME basically provides a node with inputs and outputs for each operation instead of coding to perform data analytics workflows)

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, the duplicate 0512 in the last row was a mistake, I have corrected it in my initial post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea what regex engine this knime uses.

Probably you need one that supports variable length [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to do it in one pass, eg .NET

```
\|(\d+)\b(?<=\b\1\b.*?\1)
```

[See .NET regex demo at Regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%7c%28%5cd%2b%29%5cb%28%3f%3c%3d%5cb%5c1%5cb.*%3f%5c1%29&i=0612%7c0613%7c061%7c0612%7c0612%0d%0a0211%7c0612%7c021%7c0212%7c0211%7c0211%0d%0a0111%7c0111%0d%0a0511%7c0512%7c0511%7c0511%7c0521%7c0512%7c0511%0d%0a&r=) (check [•] replace matches with, click on "context")

**Update**: Turns out knime uses Java's pattern implementation...

In Java regex variable-width lookbehind is actually implemented, but only by use of [finite repitition](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind). The second issue is, that backreference `\1` can't be used inside a lookbehind. So we'd need some trickery and put it into a look*ahead* which we put in the lookbehind.

Let's assume a maximum potential distance of 999 characters between duplicates and each field can contain up to 9 digits (adjust these values to your needs).

```
\|(\d+)\b(?<=\b(?=\|?\1\b).{1,999}?\|\d{1,9})
```

[Java regex demo at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3fAytU/1) (explanation on right side)

`0612|0613|061`
`​0211|0612|021|0212`
`​0111`
`​0511|0512|0521`

---

With only a *lookahead* you can get unique rows too, but vice versa (not like your desired results)

```
\b(\d+)\|(?=.*?\b\1\b)
```

[Another demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oa61Re/1)

`0613|061|0612`
`0612|021|0212|0211`
`0111`
`0521|0512|0511`

---

For further information have a look into the [Stackoverflow Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/5527985).

Comment: Great to see you posting answers again :-)

Comment: Thank you 4th bird, always happy reading from you:)

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. KNIME uses Java's pattern implementation. Here is the documentation for the relevant nodes:
https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.preproc.stringreplacer.StringReplacerNodeFactory
https://nodepit.com/node/ws.palladian.nodes.extraction.regex.RegexExtractorNodeFactory
It looks like I cannot implement the substitution. The string replacer only allows me to replace all occurrences of a substr matching the pattern. The regex extractor is neat, makes capturing group columns but doesn't allow substitution either. At least I couldn't get it done using these nodes ...

Comment: @citizen4 Thanks for your comment! See my updated answer. Maybe [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/P8aHin/2) works for you.

Comment: @bobblebubble Awesome! Using the String Replacer node with regex pattern type and "replace all occurrences" selected, I finally get the desired result in KNIME with the updated expression :) thank you

Comment: You're welcome! Funnily I just was doing some little edit at the same time (made the quantifier `{1,999}` [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301291/5527985) for performance reasons by attaching a `?`. Glad that trickery works for you.  Adjust the values 999/9 if not sufficient, but I think they are broad enough, aren't they.

Comment: Yes, that is sufficient because even the longest row has less than 150 char. The codes only have 3 or 4 digits, I adapted the expression accordingly ;)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the expected output shown, you can use this regex:

```bash
(\|\d+)\1(?:((?:\|\d+)*)\1)?(?=\||$)|^(\d+)\|(?=\3\b)
```

Replacement string is: `$2`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1EmRqf/1)